# QGIS 3 - ID column added as numbers with zeros after decimal

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I added a CSV file to create a point layer, each row/point designated in the original CSV file with a number ID. I then exported/saved the layer as a shapefile. The attribute table of the new shapefile shows the ID field as a number with many zeros after the decimal point. 
How can I get an integer number as an ID field without any zeros after the decimal point?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to say what *exactly* has gone wrong without more details, but dBase-III was created in the 1980s, and could not represent integers with a width exceeding 10 digits (4-byte long integer), so your problem is linked to using a field width that exceeds shapefile integer capabilities.

Comment: Thanks. But I wish to get rid of all the zeros in the field in the shapefile. From what I see, the field is type "double". I think I need it to be integer but I'm unable to change the field type. It is automatically generated as such when I save the shapefile.

Comment: We need more details on the source and how it has been generated. Note that the zeros are not part of the data, just in its display properties.

Comment: I see. If the zeros are not part of the data I suppose then that I shouldn't be concerned. The source was excel spreadsheet.

Comment: No, it's still a significant source of concern -- Floating point equality tests are likely to fail in unexpected ways (e.g., when the integer value can't be represented by IEEE floating-point representation)